# are static method in java thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading

I am thinking of using static methods whereby the input into static methods will be the only item being used to get the return value for the method.  My application will be using multiple threads.  My question is this:  do I need to synchronize/use locks for the method (or ensure that the variables being used are volatile/atomic long etc.) or since the method is static and my method is only using the input into the method to get the output (and not accessing any other objects).

Comment: If all methods called by `static` are thread safe, then it is. Otherwise it isn't.

Comment: This question is a good candidate of *vote to close* :)

Comment: You need to learn what thread safety means.

Answer (score 7):

Since `static` and thread safety are orthogonal concepts the general answer is *it depends on the code*.

Answer (score -1):

There exists only one copy of `static` variables / objects. What matters is what your method operates on.

Say your `static` method modifies a `Vector` then there is no need of synchronization. If it is modifying an `ArrayList` then you need synchronization.
If it is an object of custom class then there is a need for synchronization.

You may want to read more on thread safety =)

Comment: Please rephrase `Since the methods are static, they can only operate on static values.`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis What words are expected here ? =)

Comment: @LittleChild: Words that actually explain the right thing ;) It's fine to operate on non-static properties out of static methods, why shouldn't that be possible? `static void test(MyObject someObject) {someObject.someMember = 5; }` ;)

Comment: @JohannesH. Better now ?

Comment: @LittleChild: Better, but still not right. If you pass an instance of that class, it can modify members fine, even if they're private. The only thing (and which is most likely what you're trying to tell) that is different to non-static methods is, that there is no "this", as the method is no member of any object.

Comment: @JohannesH. Got rid of the problematic line. :D

Comment: This answer is still incorrect. It's not only the kind of data structure being operated on that matters. It's **what** the method does that is of primary importance. Imagine you have a method that first counts the elements of a vector, then removes half of them. A race condition can still occur if another thread alters the vector after the elements have been counted but before the elements are removed.

Comment: @EiríkurFannarTorfason *What matters is what your method operates on.*

Comment: Repeating that statement doesn't make it any less false. You say that no synchronization is required if a Vector object is modified, presumably because a Vector is a thread-safe object. Still, if you make several calls to the Vector object then you need to implement your own synchronization if you want to prevent the Vector from being modified between those calls.

Comment: The static method could easily be copying entries from one Vector to another and not be thread safe.  Or it could simply be reordering entries in a single Vector and not be thread safe.